# Wordpress ACF: Querying Relationship, keeping paragraph breaks

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Wordpress plugin Advanced Custom Fields to tie data together into a single post.

Here is my query for one of the relationships:

```
<?php $notes = get_field('episode_notes'); ?>
<?php if(!empty($notes)): ?>
    <?php foreach($notes as $note): ?>
        <div class="note"><?php echo $note->post_content); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `post_content` is being returned without any paragraph/line breaks (though italics, bold, etc. seem okay). I've tried this without across-the-board success:

```
<?php echo str_replace('\r','<br>', $note->post_content); ?>
```

What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)?

`<?php echo wpautop( $note->post_content, true ); ?>`